# Xamarin.Essentials.FileResult member:(null) - Media Picker

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, media, picker

I'm new on xamarin. I'm getting the following error while button `Clicked_Event` when I'm trying to pick a photo from gallery.
Error:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type of field 'App2.Views.NewDoctor+<Button_Clicked>d__5:5__1' (5) due to: Could not resolve type with token 010000a5 from typeref (expected class 'Xamarin.Essentials.FileResult' in assembly 'Xamarin.Essentials, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') assembly:Xamarin.Essentials, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null type:Xamarin.Essentials.FileResult member:(null)'

Button Code:

```cs
async void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
        {
            Title="Please Pick a photo"
        }
    );
    if (result != null)
    {
        var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();
        resultImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Label = "App2", Icon = "@mipmap/icon",ScreenOrientation =Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = false, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());

    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

}

I am using the following packages:

[image: I'm using the following packages]

AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: Update XF to 5 SR4 and Essentials 1.7 and look what happens?

Comment: But a breakpoint on first line of `Button_Clicked`.  Step through the lines under debugger (F10 key), which line generates the error message?

Comment: Show where `Button_Clicked` is used, in XAML and/or cs code.